# PHP/ MySQL select box and input

Tags: php, mysqli

I begin to learn PHP because VBA is not enough.
And today I ask you to help.
I have Select box, which takes data from MySQL.
I have Input to which I would like to enter the data from the second column, the same table with that take the data to a select box and do not know how I do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning PHP and MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819221/learning-php-and-mysql)

Comment: Alright, that's what you want - now can we see what you've tried? If you don't know where to start, you should probably Google "PHP mysql" and see where that leads. This isn't a tutorial-service ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add value from variable to input field you can do next

```
//$var you get from query from this your mysql table
<input type="text" name="somename" value="<?php echo $var['second_column']; ?>" id="someid">
```

Answer (score 0):

are you asking for how to put data into a selectbox from database ?? If so, you can use this..

```
<select name="country">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
$countriesQuery=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,name FROM countries");
while($countries=mysqli_fetch_assoc($countriesQuery))
{
echo "<option value='$countries[id]'>$countries[name]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="country">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
$countriesQuery=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,name FROM countries");
while($countries=mysqli_fetch_assoc($countriesQuery))
{
    echo "<option value='".$countries[id]."'>".$countries[name]."   </option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<?php
$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
}
$result=$mysqli->query("select name from table");
/* name is your second field*/
?>
<select name="">
<?php

while($res=$result->fetch_array())
{?>
  <option value="<?php echo $res[0]; ?>"><?php echo $res[0]; ?></option>
 <?php
}
?>
</select>
```